How to do I make the flip card feature work?
I've been trying for a while to make a flip card feature that STARTS (default) with the back face of the card and once I press the random card button I have in my form, it generates the image from the API that I have working and passes that image to the front of the card.
The PROBLEM I am having is I cannot seem to get the card to flip from the back face (default intended behavior) to the front when the button is triggered. Thus When it has been triggered again it should go back to the default state of the back of the card showing, and then it will flip back to the front with the new image again from the API. I would like to achieve this functionality.


document.getElementById("flip").onclick = function() {
  //document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block"; // Show loading indicator
  const card = document.getElementById("card");
  card.classList.add('flipped'); // Flip the card to the back
};
/* CARD FLIP  */

.card__flip__container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 450px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}


/* .card__flip__container:hover>.card {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
} */

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform .4s ease-in-out;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card-front,
.card-back {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px black;
  border-radius: 13px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card-back {
  background-color: black;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* Flip Effect */

.flipped .card-front {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  /* Flips the front out of view */
}

.flipped .card-back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  /* Flips the back into view */
}
<button type="button" id="flip">Flip</button>

<!-- Card Flip Container -->
<div class="card__flip__container">
  <div class="card" id="card">
    <div class="card-image card-front">
      <!-- Front of the card (Image) -->
      <img src="<%= card.imageUrl %>" alt="<%= card.name %>">
    </div>
    <div class="card-back">
      <!-- Back of the card (Hidden when front is showing) -->
      <p>Random Card</p>
      <!-- This represents the back side of the card -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Please use a snippet so the community can run your code directly.

@DarkBee Hi thanks, I do not know how to create the snippets. But thank you. Yes the card flips at the moment but the functionality I'm trying to achieve currently I'm struggling to impliment

In order to make the rotation on same direction, if one side goes from 0 to 180 degrees, the other side should go from 180 to 360 degrees.
Update: Trigger the flipping on the load event of the image.


function foo_flip() {
  //document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block"; // Show loading indicator
  const card = document.getElementById("card");
  card.classList.toggle('flipped');
}

document.querySelector("#flip").onclick = foo_flip;
document.querySelector(".card img").onload = foo_flip
/* CARD FLIP  */

.card__flip__container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card-front,
.card-back {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 13px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card-front {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.card-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* Flip Effect */

.flipped .card-front {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flipped .card-back {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
<button type="button" id="flip">Flip</button>

<!-- Card Flip Container -->
<div class="card__flip__container">
  <div class="card" id="card">
    <div class="card-image card-front">
      <!-- Back of the card (Hidden when front is showing) -->
      <p>Loading ...</p>
      <!-- This represents the back side of the card -->
    </div>
    <div class="card-back">
      <!-- Front of the card (Image) -->
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150" alt="Mountain Dew">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>




This has not worked it's the same in regards to functionality. I'm trying to get the card to default from the back face, but then flip to the front when the image is loaded. I assume this is only possible via javascript?

flipping initial sides is simple. as for image loaded, just add the class "flipped" when on load event of the image, instead of click event of the button.

Unfortunately I cannot seem to get this to work
